# Keeping picklists on multiple objects in sync

Tags: apex, metadata

We have picklists on a couple of different objects that we want to keep in sync. I looked at the idea exchange, but was wondering if there was a good practice way for keeping them in sync.

My idea is to run a scheduled job, weekly where I :

1. look at the fields in each picklist, and identify a difference (pretty sure I can do this)
2. add the missing values to the other picklist (not sure I can do this)

I'd appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: Universal picklists idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrfBAAS

Comment: Any special reason why it has to be a picklist and not a lookup? That'b be easiest to keep in sync ;)

Comment: @eyescream you mean keep those values in a seperate table? The context of both of the fields that we want to keep in sync is that they serve as controlling fields  in a field dependency relationship. I think controlling fields can only be checkboxes and standard picklists

Comment: "Dependency relationship"? You mean lookup filters / rollup summary filters? I think you could put Id values (but not lookup__r.Name for example) in such things. Which still sucks if you're in a developer sandbox, you create test data and Id's get different... If you mean "dependent picklists" - uh, tough... Visualforce components and/or fieldsets? Whatever you'll pick it won't be an elegant solution I'm afraid...

Comment: I'm afraid I mean dependant picklists... I'll look into field sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a picklist is just a pre-defined list of string values. You can get the picklist's values thusly:

```
    Schema.SObjectType token = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objtype);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr = token.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = dr.fields.getMap();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pickListValues = field_map.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
```

Once you've compared your two picklists ***I THINK*** you can add where needed by creating a record with the picklist field set to the new value. ie: if you have a picklist named foo on object A and Bar on object B and you find that A.foo has option "Awesome" where as B.Bar only has "Less Than Awesome" you can create the picklist Option on B by creating a new B record with Bar="Awesome"

Comment: I believe this functionality is mostly to support imports; records with non-standard values will be imported but other records will not be able to select a non-predefined value.

Comment: Yep, you can put whatever you want in a picklist value, but you can't select it in the UI with records (or in reports for that matter)

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially build out a scheduled job that calls the metadata api to do this, but im pretty sure that is not the best approach.

First I would try to get people to agree on a set of picklist values.  Why are they changing so often?  Get people to agree to a universal list of picklist values, then do one manual update.

If that isnt a realistic option, manually doing this with the force.com ide may be your best bet.  You can open the sObject metadata file, copy the picklist values XML from the object which has the correct list of picklist values, and paste it into the other sObject fields which do not have the correct list of picklist values.  It shouldnt take more than a handful of minutes to sync all your field's picklist values this way.

Comment: @phil how would record type issue be handled with that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can not programmatically add them to a picklist today.
You can write an apex job to compare the values in both fields using Describe method. If there's a difference, list which value needs to go to which field. Finally, email the list to actually add them to the picklist(manually).